# Apache Thrift installation failed on AIX7.2 server

Tags: gcc, installation, thrift

Somehow, there is no "Issues" tab available at "https://github.com/apache/thrift" so I will ask question here to see if someone can help me with Apache Thrift installation issue.

I tried to following the instruction of Apache Thrift installation on my AIX7.2 server.  `./bootstrap.sh` step has been finished without issue.  Although there are some fatal errors in `./configure --with-boost=/usr/local` step, the last line of config.log file shows `configure: exit 0` so I would expect the configure step is ok.  My issue is the `make` step.  It failed with the following error:

```
libtool: compile:  g++ -std=c++11 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I./src -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -O2 -MT src/thrift/TApplicationException.lo -MD -MP -MF src/thrift/.deps/TApplicationException.Tpo -c src/thrift/TApplicationException.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o src/thrift/.libs/TApplicationException.o
In file included from /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.2.0.0/8.3.0/include/c++/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
                 from /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.2.0.0/8.3.0/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:6400,
                 from /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.2.0.0/8.3.0/include/c++/string:52,
                 from ./src/thrift/Thrift.h:37,
                 from ./src/thrift/TApplicationException.h:23,
                 from src/thrift/TApplicationException.cpp:20:
/opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.2.0.0/8.3.0/include/c++/cstdlib:151:11: error: '::malloc' has not been declared
   using ::malloc;
           ^~~~~~
/opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.2.0.0/8.3.0/include/c++/cstdlib:164:11: error: '::realloc' has not been declared
   using ::realloc;
           ^~~~~~~
```

As far as I can see, line 151 & line 164 in /opt/freeware/lib/gcc/powerpc-ibm-aix7.2.0.0/8.3.0/include/c++/cstdlib have `using ::malloc;` and `using ::realloc;` along with lots of other `using` statements.  Below is copied from line 151 to line 164.

```
  using ::malloc;
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_MBSTATE_T
  using ::mblen;
  using ::mbstowcs;
  using ::mbtowc;
#endif // _GLIBCXX_HAVE_MBSTATE_T
  using ::qsort;
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
# ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_QUICK_EXIT
  using ::quick_exit;
# endif
#endif
  using ::rand;
  using ::realloc;
```

What's wrong with it and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: "*Somehow, there is no "Issues" tab available at Github*" -- try https://thrift.apache.org/mailing, also note the "issue tracking" link at the bottom

Comment: "*Although there are some fatal errors in ./configure*" --- if they are possibly related it may help to edit the question and add them

Comment: I don't see "issue tracking" link, but I will try "https://issues.apache.org/jira" which should be the Apache website for its issues.